# Finding the cos angle between two matrices using the euclidean inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I wanted to know if I did this problem right or not.

$A$ and $B$ are the following matrices:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\1&-3\end{bmatrix},$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$

Then

$$\frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{\|A\|\|B\|}
=\frac{\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle}{\sqrt{\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\1&-3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle}\sqrt{\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle}}.$$

I ended up getting:

$\arccos(19/184) = 84.07^\circ$

Comment: Justin: When I made the math prettier, I also took the liberty of correcting your denominator.  I hope this wasn't going too far.  I figured that it was a typo, because the expression you had was equal to $1$.  But perhaps that was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inner product is $\operatorname{tr}(AB^t)$, i.e. the inner product is the sum of the products of the entries of the matrices
$$
\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij},
$$
we have $\langle A, B\rangle=\|A\|\|B\|\cos\theta$ so
$$\theta=\arccos\Big(\frac{A\cdot B}{\|A\|\|B\|}\Big).$$
We have
$$
\langle A, B\rangle=6+12+1=19, \quad \|A\|\|B\|=\sqrt{4+36+1+9}\sqrt{9+4+1}=10\sqrt{7},
$$
so the angle is $\arccos(19/(10\sqrt{7}))$.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but there's a mistake in the answer. The process is generally correct, except that the angle calculated depends on the rank of the tensors. For a 1st rank tensor, like a vector, the above product is equal to the first Legendre polynomial, cos(theta). For a second rank, it is equal to the second Legendre polynomial, 0.5(3*cos(theta)^2 -1), and so on.